# How can I Select duplicate results, insert the results to a new table and delete them from the original table? (phpmyadmin)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables, both with the same column names that look like this

[image]

I have an app that is used for clocking in/out. A user goes up to a tablet and selects there name, the data is then inputted into table 'clocktable' as shown above.

What I need to happen is when a user presses their name for a second time (to clock out) it detects that there is already a value in the table with the same employeename value, and moves both clocks to a different table 'oldclocks' so that a record is kept of clocking in/out times. The reason it needs to be in a separate table is I have a web page that displays the 'clocktable' table so we can determine who is in the building.

How can I go about doing this? 
I can execute

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeName, time FROM clocktable ORDER BY EmployeeName
```

from within myphp and then execute

```
INSERT INTO oldclocks SELECT Employeename, Department, time FROM clocktable;
```

Afterwards, but I cannot seem to execute them both at the same time in order to get them into a php script. Also is there a way I can delete the select results from the 'clocktable' at the same time?

Help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems to me a redesign of the database AND your clocking code would be the only sensible solution here. 2 tables are unnecessary, there must be a dozen better solutions than the one you have designed

Comment: Oh and by the way `phpMyAdmin` is a tool written in PHP `MYSQL` is the DBMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an indicator, where 1 is in and 0 is out & if you want to save the logs, then creat another table to `INSERT` a record whenever the indicator's value change.

1- add 2 new attributes in `table A`, lets say `userid` & `in_out` for an example.

2- `in_out` = 1/0 where 1 is in and 0 is out

3- creat `table B` and insert `userid` & `time` every time the `in_out` value change.

And that's how you know if the user in the building or out, also you will keep logs of every move

Answer (score 2):

2 tables are not nessesary. And it is bad idea.

Why dont you simply add boolean IN_BUILDING which will have 0 ->Not in building and 1->In building. Then you can do:

`SELECT EmployeeName FROM clocktable WHERE IN_BUILDING = 0;` which will show you all employees who are not in building

or

`SELECT EmployeeName FROM clocktable WHERE IN_BUILDING = 1;` which will show you all employees who are in building that moment.

Its easier also because you can change it value easy on click.